# unable to change password using mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose, ejs

I am using MongoDB, mongoose, ejs and NodeJS for my site. I have a update password function which is not working properly. I have checked again and again by login different things in console and there is no problem in getting data in req. So I guess my problem is in the controller. This is my controller:

```
module.exports.update_password = function (req, res) {
    console.log(req.user);
    Company.findOne({ username: req.user.username }, function (err, user) {
        if (user.password == req.body.current_password) {
            if (req.body.new_password == req.body.confirm_password) {
                Company.findOneAndUpdate({ username: req.user.username }, { password: req.body.new_password }, { upsert: true }, function (err, doc) {
                    if (err) return res.send(500, { error: err });
                    req.flash('notify', 'Password changed!')
                    return res.redirect('/profile');
                });
            }
            else req.flash('notify', 'New password does not match with confirm password');
        }
        else req.flash('notify', '!')
    });
    return res.redirect('/profile');
}
```

everytime updating my password I get this error:

```
node:events:355
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^

Error [ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT]: Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client
    at new NodeError (node:internal/errors:329:5)
    at ServerResponse.setHeader (node:_http_outgoing:573:11)
    at ServerResponse.header (/home/krush/github/Project_Lightspeed/node_modules/express/lib/response.js:771:10)
    at ServerResponse.location (/home/krush/github/Project_Lightspeed/node_modules/express/lib/response.js:888:15)
    at ServerResponse.redirect (/home/krush/github/Project_Lightspeed/node_modules/express/lib/response.js:926:18)
    at /home/krush/github/Project_Lightspeed/controllers/authentication_controller.js:45:32
    at /home/krush/github/Project_Lightspeed/node_modules/mongoose/lib/model.js:4857:16
    at /home/krush/github/Project_Lightspeed/node_modules/mongoose/lib/model.js:4857:16
    at /home/krush/github/Project_Lightspeed/node_modules/mongoose/lib/helpers/promiseOrCallback.js:24:16
    at /home/krush/github/Project_Lightspeed/node_modules/mongoose/lib/model.js:4880:21
    at /home/krush/github/Project_Lightspeed/node_modules/mongoose/lib/query.js:4397:11
    at /home/krush/github/Project_Lightspeed/node_modules/kareem/index.js:136:16
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:76:11)
Emitted 'error' event on Function instance at:
    at /home/krush/github/Project_Lightspeed/node_modules/mongoose/lib/model.js:4859:13
    at /home/krush/github/Project_Lightspeed/node_modules/mongoose/lib/helpers/promiseOrCallback.js:24:16
    [... lines matching original stack trace ...]
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:76:11) {
  code: 'ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT'
}
[nodemon] app crashed - waiting for file changes before starting...
```

Comment: Please check out: [Under what circumstances may I add "urgent" or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that the problem is that the `return res.redirect('/profile');` command is executed before your callback functions. Which is normal since this is how the event loop works.

Try to remove the `return res.redirect('/profile');` line to see if the error goes away. Callbacks at node.js execute at a later stage of the event loop.

Generally I would recommend to refactor your code to use promises instead of callbacks since that causes the "callback hell" anti-pattern.

If you refactor your code to use promises, then you will be able to use .then or async await, which will help you write cleaner code and help you spot any error easily.

Comment: Thanks a lot!!! that worked. Just a followup question. If I still want to use `return res.redirect('/profile')` then what do I do?

Comment: As I mentioned in my previous comment, the best way is to refactor your code using promises. If you do not want to do that, you should add the return res.redirect('/profile'); statement inside all the if else blocks you want, according to the business logic you want to implement.